# My datetime is increasing by 12.30 hours on server when retrieving from client side from ajax call

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

The date in database is:8/29/2013 15:27 and i am converting it into a json date and sending it to the client side as a json date .after converting json date in javascript date it is showing me the date is 8/30/2013 3:57 here is my code

```
$.get("League/GetMatchupDates", { sportId: spo }, function (data) {
            debugger;
            for (i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
                debugger;
                if (data[i] != undefined) {
                    var parsedDate = new Date(parseFloat(/Date\(([^)]+)\)/.exec(data[i])[1]));
```

Comment: if anyone is here please help me

Comment: You will have to show your code first. The way you are converting this Date to JSON and passing it to the client and the way you are handling it on the client.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "JSON date".

Comment: Welcome to the horrifying world of time zones.  You should use UTC everywhere.

Comment: Javascript dates always convert to the local timezone. Use a javascript date library to help untangle that mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a timezone difference.  Stick to UTC programmatically and only use timezones when outputting to a user.